# Return data from json in function

Tags: reactjs

I have json file in my react project. It contains all data. I am trying to output data but it returns nothing. Help me please.

this.props.id is 2, so i try to find data in my json with 2 then to map exercise and get title and id. But smt gets wrong. I will be thankful if you help me!

```
[
    {
    "id":1,
    "title": "first"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "title": "second",
    "exercise": [
        {
        "id":1, 
        "title": "one"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "title": "two"
    }
]
    }
]
```

Code:

```js
..//

    getData() {
        let findData = jsonExercises.find(item => item.id === this.props.id)
        if (findData) {
            findData.exercise.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div>
    <div>
                <Text}>{item.title}</Text>
    </div>
               </div>
                )
            });
       } }
        

    render() {
        return (
            
           <div style={{ padding: 10}}>       
             {this.getData()}  
   </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonExercises.find` will give you just the object and not the array. And I believe you just want to have the cases where exercise have titles, just like id=2, so just return only one parent div

```
     getData() {
            let findData = jsonExercises.find(item => item.id === this.props.id)
           
                
                   return (
    <div>
    {findData.exercise.map(item => {
                            <div>
           
                        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
           
                       </div>
    
                        
                    })
    }
    </div>
    )
           } 
            
    
        render() {
            return (
                
               <div style={{ padding: 10}}>       
                 {this.getData()}  
       </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what i need to do? Help me please

Comment: I have updated the code. I believ you need to put condition that will avoid id=1, elements from printing

Comment: it also returns nothing

Comment: I have moved it inside of return. Try now

Comment: Removed indentation errors. Try now. You need to return just one div

Comment: Great to hear that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@Raghavendar is right about it. However jsonExercises.find will only return an object if the id matches your prop id. If not it will return undefined. So what you can do is check if the returned value is object or not and then you can proceed with your rendering part.